# how to initialize static variable before initialize page and before running initstate method in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want fetch data from web service and fill variable with fetched data but before run my await method run init state method and my variable get null value in new page how solve it.i run this method before super.init state method but do not work

Comment: HI @mohammed, welcome to stack overflow. Could you provide us with more detail here about the things you have tried. Showing some of your code would also be super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a function inside your Stateful widget that executes what you want to accomplish and call it inside the InitState function.

This is an example from my Clima app where I fetch data from an API and I put them inside some variables:

```
//This is an example

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateUI(widget.locationWeather);
  }

  void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
    setState(() {
      if (weatherData == null) {
        temperature = 0;
        condition = 'Error';
        message = 'Unable to get location';
        cityName = '';
        return;
      }
      double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
      temperature = temp.toInt();
      condition = weatherModel.getWeatherIcon(weatherData['weather'][0]['id']);
      cityName = weatherData['name'];
      message = weatherModel.getMessage(temperature);
    });
  }
```

Comment: it is ok but my variable has static and my method is async method

Comment: You can try to set a temp variable and then pass that value to the static variable thanks to the function.Just let the function return that value

Comment: my local server is not available but i will say you your answer is usage or not but thank for help you but when you invoke super.initState(); in initstate is first initialize page Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, initState is called when the page builds

Comment: If you want you can check my answer as the right one <3